# CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS uploading files of 0 bytes

Tags: file-upload, meteor, dropbox-api, collectionfs

I am trying to upload files to a dropbox app. Using the package [CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) with the [cfs:dropbox](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/tree/devel/packages/dropbox) adapter and my problem is that the files being uploaded is 0 bytes. I am not sure what I am missing or doing wrong here.

On server:

```
var registrationImageStorage = new FS.Store.Dropbox("registrationStorage", {
  key: "****",
  secret: "****",
  token: "****",
  transformWrite: function (fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).stream().pipe(writeStream);
  }
});

RegistrationImages = new FS.Collection("registrations", {
  stores: [registrationImageStorage],
  filter: {
    allow: {
      contentTypes: ['image/*']
    }
  }
});

RegistrationImages.allow({
  insert: function () {
    return true;
  },
  update: function () {
    return true;
  }
});
```

On client:

```
var registrationImageStorage = new FS.Store.Dropbox("registrationStorage");

RegistrationImages = new FS.Collection("registrations", {
  stores: [registrationImageStorage],
  filter: {
    allow: {
      contentTypes: ['image/*']
    }
  }
});
```

On client to start the upload:

```
var file = new FS.File($('#badgeImage').get(0).files[0]);

    RegistrationImages.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(fileObj);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I did not need this part of the code and after removing it, it worked:

```
transformWrite: function (fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).stream().pipe(writeStream);
  }
```